# How to solve Android license issue

Tags: android

After using **flutter doctor** in command prompt, I found the below problem

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
 X Android license status unknown. 
   Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or
visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

I then tried **flutter doctor --android-licenses** in command prompt, this is what I got,

```
Android sdkmanager tool not found (D:\Softwares\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK, visit
https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

My Android is up to date and I also tried reinstalling the whole thing, but I still keep getting this message.

Answer (score 0):

You must select this option when installing Android Studio, so you don't have to do it manually afterwards

[image: Screenshot]